# Setting up Dual Lan to Access Two Different Networks

Tags: network-protocols, lan

I have two ISP connections 
Say A and B.
A : connects 7 PCs and a Network Multi Function Device + Internet
B : High Speed Internet Connection connects only my PC

I want to access Devices on A and simultaneously use Connection B for normal Internet browsing. I have dual Lan Cards but still cant figure out how to configure them, is it even possible.

Answer (score 0):

It just started working automatically. 
 I set static IP for Connection A and Connected to Internet through Connection B using Dial Up. And it worked. Nothing Extra 
Now I can access my Local Network and use Network devices as usuall while accessing Internet from another Connection.